# how to organize this code to load report after window is shown?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, crystal-reports

Im trying to load a xml file into a dataset and generate crystal report with loaded data.

im using Crystal Reports WPF Application for the project.

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        reportViewer.Owner = this;

        DataSet dset = new DataSet1();

        DataSet reportData = new DataSet();
        reportData.ReadXml("http://192.168.1.10/test/persons.xml");

        dset.Tables[0].Merge(reportData.Tables[0]); 


        ReportDocument report = null;
        report = new CrystalReport1();
        report.SetDataSource(dset.Tables[0]);
        reportViewer.ViewerCore.ReportSource = report;
    }

}
```

This working fine and my question is how to move download xml and set report codes to a different event to load report after the application is shown?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Window Lifetime Management events: ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.aspx))

- Activated
- Closed
- Closing
- Deactivated
- SourceInitialized

I believe `Activated` event is what you need. Considering that `Activated` event fires not only when a window opened first time but also when <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> switches and so on so to filter out first windo opening from other Activated events just use boolean flag setting it to true when first time `Activated` event was handled:

```
    bool firstActivateAlreadyHandled = false;
    protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnActivated(e);

        if (!this.firstActivateAlreadyHandled)
        {
             // your code here
             this.firstActivateAlreadyHandled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: i used protected override void OnContentRendered(EventArgs e) method and it seems works fine

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% certain what you are after, if you want to handle the download of the file elsewhere then you could read the remote file, save it locally and then once saved update the report then, if you are looking at just handling the remote file once the window shows then i'm not sure, i'm assuming you mean a form which means on a form you would do something like this:

```
Private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            DataSet dset = new DataSet1();

            DataSet reportData = new DataSet();
            reportData.ReadXml("http://192.168.1.10/test/persons.xml");

            dset.Tables[0].Merge(reportData.Tables[0]); 


            ReportDocument report = null;
            report = new CrystalReport1();
            report.SetDataSource(dset.Tables[0]);
            reportViewer.ViewerCore.ReportSource = report;

}
```

As you have said it is for WPF try....

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            DataSet dset = new DataSet1();

            DataSet reportData = new DataSet();
            reportData.ReadXml("http://192.168.1.10/test/persons.xml");

            dset.Tables[0].Merge(reportData.Tables[0]); 


            ReportDocument report = null;
            report = new CrystalReport1();
            report.SetDataSource(dset.Tables[0]);
            reportViewer.ViewerCore.ReportSource = report;
}
```

or

```
private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            DataSet dset = new DataSet1();

            DataSet reportData = new DataSet();
            reportData.ReadXml("http://192.168.1.10/test/persons.xml");

            dset.Tables[0].Merge(reportData.Tables[0]); 


            ReportDocument report = null;
            report = new CrystalReport1();
            report.SetDataSource(dset.Tables[0]);
            reportViewer.ViewerCore.ReportSource = report;
}
```

Comment: im looking for something similar to this though, but it seems in WPF application shown is not work.

Comment: nothing happens application open as normal but report won't load.

Comment: hmmm try content rendered, also add some sort of Console.WriteLine() in there so you can see if it is being called (sorry don't know WPF equivalent for console)

Comment: inside public Window1() {} Console.WriteLine() works and inside Window_ContentRendered or Window_Loaded nothing happens

Answer (score -1):

If you are concerned about UI response i.e. your loading stops the application flow, you can start it in a different thread. Just wrap it like this.

```
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    new Task(() =>
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            reportViewer.Owner = this;

            DataSet dset = new DataSet1();

            DataSet reportData = new DataSet();
            reportData.ReadXml("http://192.168.1.10/test/persons.xml");

            dset.Tables[0].Merge(reportData.Tables[0]);


            ReportDocument report = null;
            report = new CrystalReport1();
            report.SetDataSource(dset.Tables[0]);
            reportViewer.ViewerCore.ReportSource = report;
        }), null);
    }).Start();
}
```

Comment: yeah it takes time to load application, but i have no idea how to use this code though

Comment: seems like this is the way i needed but once its running im getting error at line  reportData.ReadXml("http://192.168.1.10/test/persons.xml");   The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine

Comment: -1.  This does not guarantee that it will be shown after the form is displayed, which the OP wants.  Also, this is a bad coding practice for loading data in the constructor.

Comment: It's hard to control when the data is loaded since it is retrieved from a remote source. And why is it a bad practice to load data in the constructor? Can you point me to some link that explains why is it a bad practice?